# How to direct to a webpage in urls.py without using a view

Tags: python, django

I am trying to create an index page for my home app using Django. I would like for the `urls.py` file to point directly to an `index.html` file in my templates folder within the home app. Therefore, I have the following:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',url(r'^$',template_name='index.html'),)
```

This gives me an error when I load the page, however.

```
url() got an unexpected keyword argument 'template_name'.
```

All the resources I have looked at have a view instead of directly linking to an html, but I simply want to go to an index page. How can I achieve this? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

As per [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/class-based-views/):

This would be a proper way of doing it:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^about/', TemplateView.as_view(template_name="about.html")),
)
```